# laravel4 form post data

Tags: forms, post, laravel-4

```
<form  action=""  id="pb-signup-form">
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <div class="pb-signup-box">
                        <div class="pb-signup-box-main-box">
                            <label class="pb-login-usr-txt"> Sign up @ Popibay </label>
                            <input name="pb-signup-name" class="validate[required] text-input pb-all-inputs" type="text" placeholder="Name" id="pb-signup-box-email">
                            <input name="pb-signup-othername" class="pb-all-inputs" type="text" placeholder="Othername" id="pb-login-box-pass">
                                      <input name="pb-signup-surname" class="validate[required] text-input pb-all-inputs" type="text" placeholder="Surname" id="pb-signup-box-email">
                                      <input name="pb-signup-username" class="validate[required] text-input pb-all-inputs" type="text" placeholder="Username" id="pb-signup-box-email">
                                      <input name="pb-signup-email" class="validate[required,custom[email]] text-input pb-all-inputs" type="email" placeholder="Email" id="pb-login-box-pass">
                                      <input name="pb-signup-password" class="validate[required] text-input pb-all-inputs" type="password" placeholder="Password" id="pb-login-box-pass">
                                      <!-- <input name="pb-signup-cpassword"  class="validate[required,equals[password]] password-input pb-all-inputs" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" id="pb-signup-box-email"> -->
                            <button class="pb-all-buttons" type="submit" id="pb-hm-hd-but-login">Log-in</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </form>
```

I am using the laravel4 framework and i have this form i am using to post this form to the server for database input. also i noticed some when i added a post method to the form it produced an error.

```
<form  action="post"  id="pb-signup-form">
```

**Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException**

so how do i send a form to the database? Please with nice explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined your route?  When Laravel says "NotFoundHttpException", that's usually what it means.

Define your post route. Also, 'post' is an html/http form method, not action.

```
action='route | url'   

<form action="url | route" method="post"> ...inputs... </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add an action to your form like:

```
<form  action="post"  id="pb-signup-form" action="{{link_to('/myroute')}}">
```

and then create a route in your routes.php file:

```
Route::post('/myroute', 'myController@myFunction');
```

You then have to create myController with a method myFunction, in your 'controllers folder'.
To access the data use:

```
$input = Input::all();
```